# How to make NonNullable in TypeScript prevent null assignment?

Tags: typescript

I understand that `NonNullable` is meant to remove `null` and `undefined` as valid values for a type, but it seems it is not working as expected.

I have the following code:

```
interface User {
    name: string;
}


type NonNullableUser = NonNullable<User>;
let user1 : NonNullable<User> = { name: "foo"}
let user2 : NonNullable<User> = null // expect this to lead to a type error
```

I expect `let user2 : NonNullable<User> = null` to not compile but it still does! Note, I set the
`strictNullChecks` to off, because if I set it to on, the compiler automatically prevents `null` assignment and `let user2: User = null` would lead to a compile error removing the need for the utility type `NonNullable`.

If I need to have `strictNullChecks` on for this work, then I wonder if `NonNullable` is not redundant then?

Or perhaps I do not get how to make use of `NonNullable`? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note, I set the strictNullChecks to off, because if I set it to on,
> the compiler automatically prevents null assignment and let user2:
> User = null would lead to a compile error

This is your problem. With `strictNullChecks` off, `null` and `undefined` are assignable to *everything*. With it on they are only assignable to types that are *explicitly* typed as `null` or `undefined`. It is generally recommended to always have `strictNullChecks` on if you can.

> removing the need for the utility type NonNullable.

That's not the case. With `strictNullChecks` on you can still *explicitly* specify that a type is nullable, and `NonNullable` will remove `null`/`undefined` from the type.

e.g.

```
interface User {
    name: string;
}

type NullableUser = User | null;

const user1: NullableUser = null;

type NonNullableUser = NonNullable<NullableUser>;

const user2: NonNullableUser = null; // Type error
```

Comment: so if I get it, NonNullable is used to remove `null | undefined` from types you explicitly create to have  `null | undefined`? Sounds not very useful to me. or perhaps I am not imaginative enough to see where this could be useful :/

Comment: I mean why not just have `User` and `NullableUser` types?

Comment: It's a contrived example just to illustrate how it works. Remember that not all code in your program is going to be written by you. You might be importing code from a third party library with a nullable type and want to convert it to non-nullable.

Comment: I guess. Thanks all  the same. I think the part I was missing was understanding that this applies only to union types. Now I need to be more imaginative so think of the scenario where this would be useful :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [`NonNullable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) utility type doesn't operate on object properties but on the object type itself.

We could introduce a custom utility type to exclude `null` and `undefined` from all properties of the object:

```
type NonNullableValues<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: NonNullable<T[P]>;
};

interface User {
    name: string | null;
}

type NullableUser = NonNullableValues<User>;
// type NullableUser = { name: string }
```